# Sistema de tentativas de login seguro php

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber como vocês fazem um sistema de login seguro.

Pois é dificil obter informações do usuário que vai tentar logar:

Ex:

```
echo getenv("username").'<br>';
echo getenv("REMOTE_ADDR").'<br>';
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $hostname.'<br>';
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Como eu faria um sistema que bloquea-se tantas tentativas de login.

Eu não falo da questão de código, pois geralmente quando faço, eu salvo os IPs no banco de dados, e conto as tentativas de login fracassadas nos últimos 30 minutos, se maior que 5, eu redireciono a página...

Isso é fácil, o problema, se a pessoa estiver em uma rede. Daí vai bloquear o acesso de todos com o mesmo IP.

Eu poderia diferenciar usando o nome do PC e do usuário, mas essa função não funciona no meu servido linux...

Já o User agente, também não é nada confiável, pois a pessoa pode alterar facilmente.

Já esse nome do Host(gethostbyaddr), achei interessante, pode ser um adicional para um sistema de Login.

Session, se o cara fechar o browser, ou eliminar a session, já era.

Cookie a mesma coisa...

Captcha, pode ser um adicional, mas não garante nada...

1 - Existem outras funções que peguem mais dados do usuário? 
2 - Qual a melhor maneira de criar um sistema seguro de login, evitando que a pessoa tente logar várias vezes gerando erro. 
3 - O que os principais sites usam para bloquear usuários maliciosos, que tentam logar várias vezes seguidas?

Comment: Se junto com o IP você salvar o username de quem tentou logar, não resolve o problema de vários usuários na mesma rede? Aí você pode ter uma verificação separada, com um limite maior de tentativas, que considere só o IP.

Comment: Interessante a maneira como você coloca, seria mais um extra...

Comment: Interessante pensar dessa forma, quantas tentativas você deixaria dessa maneira? e por quanto tempo? E se eles tentarem entrar com mais de um usuário diferente? O que você fariam? Imagina que a cada 10 tentativas erradas em 30 minutos eu bloquea-se, mas o cara tenta outros usuários diferentes, assim não iria bloquear... O que fazer numa situação dessa?

Comment: Você pode criar uma solução mais complexa, como armazenar um ID do usuário em `localStorage` já que este é mais persistente que `Cookies`. Porém ainda sim é facilmente burlável. No geral salvar um IP associado a usuário em uma tabela de bloqueio deve ser mais do que suficiente. Se o usuário tentar utilizar outro's login's você pode pensar em bloquear o IP por completo como medida de segurança. No geral se o usuário desejar realmente ficar tentando logins diferentes ele irá conseguir, nem que seja trocando de IP's.

Comment: Andei analisando o Hotmail. Tentei umas 20 vezes com uns 4 e-mail diferentes, alguns nem existiam. Onde vejo uma falha do hotmail, pois eles retornam que o e-mail não existe. Fica fácil descobrir se um usuário existe. Caso o usuário exista, eu acho que ele dá umas 10 tentativas de login.  Ele bloqueia, mas é só remover o método post que funciona normalmente. Obviamente que tentei poucas vezesmenos de 30.

Comment: Após mais outras tentativas ele adicionou um captcha, mas como falei anteriormente, remove o método PoST que você digita novamente usuário e senha... outra coisa que percebi, que após digitar senha errada várias vezes ele bloqueia na primeira tentativa de um e-mail correto...